# Why can't clang++ deduce this lambda's return value?

Tags: g++, c++14, clang++, stdmap

Consider the following function:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template<template<class, class> class Map, typename Key, typename Value , typename F>
auto transform_values(const Map<Key,Value>& map, const F& value_mapper)
{
    using mapped_value_type = decltype(value_mapper(std::declval<Value>()));
    Map<Key, mapped_value_type> transformed;
    std::transform(map.cbegin(), map.cend(), std::inserter(transformed, transformed.begin()),
        [&value_mapper](const auto& pair) {
            const auto& key = pair.first;
            const auto& value = pair.second;
            return {key, value_mapper(value)};
        }
    );
    return transformed;
}
```

[g++ 12 accepts this, clang++ 14 does not](https://godbolt.org/z/GnacEPMs1) (GodBolt). clang++ 14 says:

```
<source>:15:20: error: cannot deduce lambda return type from initializer list
            return {key, value_mapper(value)};
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why won't it deduce the lambda's type?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but GCC rejects your code if you actually call the function. Also, what type is it supposed to deduce to and why?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: So... I guess either an initializer list?

Comment: You mean `std::initializer_list`? If yes, with what template argument?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Hmm, yeah, you have a point there.

Comment: `return std::make_pair(key, value_mapper(value));` will work.  Although in there you are exposing `std::map` private parts and that will not compile. [Godbolt is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/hsbM1Gcvh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I can't see how the compiler can deduce return type here. The return type of the lambda should be convertible to the type pointed to by the output iterator, but without complete container class it doesn't even know what this type is.</s>

**Edit.**
For the part what rule makes it fail (i.e. why no valid specialization can be generated), i believe it refers to [9.2.9.6.2 Placeholder type deduction / 2.1.2 rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#dcl.type.auto.deduct-2.1.2):

> A type T containing a placeholder type, and a corresponding initializer-
> clause E, are determined as follows:
>
> For a non-discarded return statement that occurs in a function declared with a return type that contains a placeholder type, T is the declared return type.
>
> ...
>
> - If the operand is a braced-init-list ([dcl.init.list]), the program is ill-formed.

Comment: If the compiler doesn't know what that type is yet, why is clang failing me already?

Comment: No matter the container type, the lambda by itself is illegal.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: So, g++ is in the wrong here, then? PS - I didn't downvote.

Comment: @einpoklum Neither of them is wrong, but Clang is more correct. The code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, due to http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i might be missing something, but the lambda is illegal *because* container type is a template. If it was a complete class, the lambda would be legal here

Comment: You mean like this? https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nGW8df6MG Still broken.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are right, my bad. it will have a placeholder return type anyway.